# ubuntu 22.04 overheats my laptop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, lenovo, overheating

My laptop specs:

- brand: Lenovo
- model: Lenovo ThinkPad T420s
- RAM: 4GB
- HDD: 500GB
- graphic card: NVIDIA nvs 4200m
- processor: Intel® Core™ i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4I

I used windows 10 since my laptop did not work well, I decided to use linux
currently I am using ***Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS*** but since I installed Ubuntu, my laptop began  overheating

I installed graphics drivers but still keeps overheating
I tried installing proprietary drivers
I tried open source drives
I tried bumblebee
I tried thermald

but none of them worked and my laptop still keeps overheating

Comment: Search for System Monitor in Applications or run `top` command in terminal to find which process is using the resources unnecessarily(Eg. CPU or RAM) and paste the output or a screenshot here.

Comment: As usual with older computers: Check the Bios battery ! Besides this, can you be sure all the heat spreaders are attached correctly (sitting tight, enough thermal paste) and all fans are "dust-free" ?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. After the Ubuntu install complete, it tries to make a file index while idle. It's completely normal the laptop heats up around 50°C, you can add ventilation to the laptop or rest it. However, the heat problem often caused by hardware problem, especially dusty fan and air intakes. Use your vacuum cleaner.